# Flutter: popup menu inside popup menu

Tags: flutter

I need to achieve a list of PopUpMenu nested inside a PopUpMenu.
On click on one of the itmes I want to get another PopUpMenu with it's own items.

We could say it maight look similar to classic windows options.

Is it possible to achievie in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can:

This show two subMenu with two items each.
I used an enum for the demo:
`enum Item { i1, i2, i3, i4 }`

Make sure to call `Navigator.pop(context)` in the onSelected to close the first menu.

```
PopupMenuButton(
              
              child: Text('MENU'),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<PopupMenuButton>>[
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: PopupMenuButton(
                    child: Text('SUBMENU A'),
                    onSelected: (Item result) { 
                      setState(() { _selection = result; });
                    Navigator.pop(context); },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<Item>>[
                      const PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                        value: Item.i1,
                        child: Text('i1'),
                        ),
                      const PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                        value: Item.i2,
                        child: Text('i2'),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ),
                
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: PopupMenuButton(
                    child: Text('SUBMENU B'),
                    onSelected: (Item result) { 
                      setState(() { _selection = result; });
                      Navigator.pop(context); },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<Item>>[
                      const PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                        value: Item.i3,
                        child: Text('i3'),
                        ),
                      const PopupMenuItem<Item>(
                        value: Item.i4,
                        child: Text('i4'),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Adding to the answer - assigning values to PopupMenuItems is not optional. The onSelected does not get called if value is not assigned, and hence the menu won't get dismissed on selection.

Comment: For some reason `PopupMenuItem(child: PopupMenuButton(child: Text("title")` doe snot work for me - the menu is just not shown.

Comment: To close first menu Navigator.pop(context) at onSelected of first menu will not work . i have to use it in onOpened() of submenu.

Answer (score 2):

you can get nested pop up menus like this :

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
  itemBuilder: (_) {
    return [
      PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item1")),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: PopupMenuButton(
          child: Text("Nested Items"),
          itemBuilder: (_) {
            return [
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item2")),
              PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item3"))
            ];
          },
        ),
      ),
    ];
  },
)
```

Comment: How can i get the nested popup to be positioned outside of the main popup? like next to it instead of inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, add it to code.

```
class PopupMenuChildrenItem<T> extends PopupMenuEntry<T> {
  const PopupMenuChildrenItem({
    super.key,
    this.height = kMinInteractiveDimension,
    this.padding,
    this.enable = true,
    this.textStyle,
    this.onTap,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    required this.child,
  });

  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final bool enable;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final List<PopupMenuEntry<T>> Function(BuildContext) itemBuilder;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  final double height;

  @override
  bool represents(T? value) => false;

  @override
  MyPopupMenuItemState<T, PopupMenuChildrenItem<T>> createState() => MyPopupMenuItemState<T, PopupMenuChildrenItem<T>>();
}

class MyPopupMenuItemState<T, W extends PopupMenuChildrenItem<T>> extends State<W> {
  @protected
  void handleTap(T value) {
    widget.onTap?.call();

    Navigator.pop<T>(context, value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final PopupMenuThemeData popupMenuTheme = PopupMenuTheme.of(context);
    TextStyle style = widget.textStyle ??
        popupMenuTheme.textStyle ??
        theme.textTheme.subtitle1!;

    return PopupMenuButton<T>(
      enabled: widget.enable,
      onSelected: handleTap,
      itemBuilder: widget.itemBuilder,
      child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
        style: style,
        duration: kThemeChangeDuration,
        child: Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: widget.height),
          padding: widget.padding ?? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, use it like

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
      child: const Text('MENU'),
      onSelected: (result) {
        setState(() {
          _selection = result;
        });
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
        PopupMenuChildrenItem(
          child: const Text('SUBMENU A'),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
            const PopupMenuItem(
              value: 1,
              child: Text('1'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem(
              value: 2,
              child: Text('2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        PopupMenuChildrenItem(
          child: const Text('SUBMENU B'),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
            const PopupMenuItem(
              value: 3,
              child: Text('3'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem(
              value: 4,
              child: Text('4'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 5,
          child: Text('5'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 6,
          child: Text('6'),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: also add some supporting informations